# php executing partial sql query

Tags: php, sql, partial, execute

I have this query which is executing partially. Only the `start_date` is getting updated not the description.

```
 $query = "UPDATE cbv_ani_block
    SET start_date = today, description = '$desc'
    WHERE blocked_ani = '$blocked_ani'";
```

This is the echo from same statement, but if I execute the same statement in sql it runs fine, the problem is when I run it through php by passing variables. there is no error message.

```
UPDATE cbv_ani_block
SET start_date = today, description = 'Test Number'
WHERE blocked_ani = '1-604-9615326';
```

Comment: What is your SQL structure, specifically for the column description. Seems like what your passing to description doesn't fit the data model.

Comment: Are you sure the start_date is getting updated? Maybe it already was today. Can you post more of the surrounding code, maybe the problem is with the way you're executing the query. Or are you embarassed to show it because you're still using mysql_* instead of mysqli_*?

Comment: 2 tips: one - use `echo mysql_error()` after executing the query.
two - use `echo $desc;` before the query (maybe it's empty!).

Comment: @Barmar no i am not embarassed actually i am using odbc not mysql

Comment: @OfirBaruch thanks ofir actually i did echo out query, the problem was whitespaces. so i trimmed the variable n it ran fine Thanks for your help